# API Data being returned with Commas after each letter - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

Looking for some guidance on two issues.

I'm calling data from an API  - (https://opendata.dc.gov/datasets/7fa33d79592c412a95a1f14c026c6dc0/api) with two outfields (Name, Address)

But it returns the names and address data with a comma after every letter. So something like
"Ft. Stevens Garden" is instead displaying as:
F,t,., ,S,t,e,v,e,n,s, ,G,a,r,d,e,n

How can I remedy this so that it doesn't do this?

```
const APIURL =
  'https://maps2.dcgis.dc.gov/dcgis/rest/services/DCGIS_DATA/Environment_Land_WebMercator/MapServer/54/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=NAME,ADDRESS&outSR=4326&f=json';

async function fetchFeatures() {
  try {
    const list = await fetch(`${APIURL}`);

    let json = await list.json();
    // getFeatures(json);
    // console.log('Testing this', json);
    return json;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
}

const createListingItem = listGardenName =>
  `<h1 id="listingName">${listGardenName}</h1>`;

const getFeatures = async () => {
  const data = await fetchFeatures();

  const titles = data.features.map(gardenNames => gardenNames.attributes);

  for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    let gardenNames = [];
    let gardenAddress = [];

    for (const property in titles) {
      gardenNames.push(`${Object.values(titles[property].NAME)}`);
      gardenAddress.push(`${Object.values(titles[property].ADDRESS)}`);

      // gardenNames.push(`${property}: ${Object.values(titles[property])}`);
      // console.log(obj['name']);
    }
    gardenBlock.classList.remove('none');

    const listGardenName = gardenNames.map(t => createListingItem(t)).join('');
    document.getElementById('listingName').innerHTML = listGardenName;

    const listGardenAddress = gardenAddress
      .map(t => createListingItem(t))
      .join('');
    document.getElementById('listingAddress').innerHTML = listGardenAddress;
  }
};
```

The second issue is that I want the data that's stored in the gardenNames and gardenAddress arrays to show together. So that the name for the garden has the address for that garden under it. When I try to add gardenAddress into createListingItem it either shows as undefined if I code it one way, or it displays all of the addresses but only after all of the names have been listed.

This is my first time calling data from an API and I would appreciate any insight - I've been lurking around stack overflow and implemented the coding solution from this question: [Why is my code returning a comma after every element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64093642/why-is-my-code-returning-a-comma-after-every-element) but it still shows the comma after each letter when I format the code to match.

If there's any resources to read that anyone would recommend and would like to share, I would really appreciate it.

When I have the code formatted as the below it shows the garden names and addresses together, but I want to be able to format the name and address in different styles in css so I don't think I can use this:

```
const createListingItem = item => `<div class="garden">${item}</div>`;

const getFeatures = async () => {
  const data = await fetchFeatures();

  const titles = data.features.map(gardenNames => gardenNames.attributes);

  for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    let gardenNames = [];

    for (const property in titles) {
      gardenNames.push(`${property}: ${Object.values(titles[property])}`);
    }

    const listItems = gardenNames.map(t => createListingItem(t)).join('');
    document.getElementById('listings').innerHTML = listItems;
  }
};
```

Thank you for any tips or guidance. I will be rampaging google and resources in the meantime to try to figure this out.

Comment: Why are you calling `Object.values` on the strings? That's most likely the source of your problem.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior thank you so much!! That did solve the first problem; for some reason I thought I had to have Object.values on it - will do more reading on this so I don't confuse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of those `Object.values`: they aren't necessary, and they're causing your first problem.

For your second problem, use separate HTML elements to represent the name and address. Use classes for styling, since `id` properties are supposed to be unique.

```
const createListingItem = (garden) =>
  `<div class="garden">
    <h1 class="garden-name">${garden.name}</h1>
    <h2 class="garden-address">${garden.address}</h2>
  </div>`;
const getFeatures = async () => {
  const data = await fetchFeatures();
  const gardenData = data.features.map(feature => ({
    name: feature.attributes.NAME,
    address: feature.attributes.ADDRESS
  }));
  var listHtml = gardenData.map(garden => createListingItem(garden)).join('');
  document.getElementById('listings').innerHTML = listHtml;
});
```

I hard-coded a couple of the results in the snippet below to show how this would work.

```js
const data = {
    "displayFieldName": "NAME",
    "fieldAliases": {
        "NAME": "Name",
        "ADDRESS": "Address"
    },
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 4326,
        "latestWkid": 4326
    },
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "NAME",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
            "alias": "Name",
            "length": 255
        },
        {
            "name": "ADDRESS",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
            "alias": "Address",
            "length": 255
        }
    ],
    "features": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "NAME": "Ft. Stevens Garden",
                "ADDRESS": "1327 VAN BUREN STREET NW"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "x": -77.030969558051225,
                "y": 38.970534392122069
            }
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "NAME": "Rock Creek Garden",
                "ADDRESS": "OREGON AVENUE NW AND NORTHAMPTON STREET NW"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "x": -77.053619710910311,
                "y": 38.966722603548469
            }
        }
    ]
};
const createListingItem = (garden) =>
  `<div class="garden">
    <h1 class="garden-name">${garden.name}</h1>
    <h2 class="garden-address">${garden.address}</h2>
  </div>`;
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const gardenData = data.features.map(feature => ({
    name: feature.attributes.NAME,
    address: feature.attributes.ADDRESS
  }));
  var listHtml = gardenData.map(garden => createListingItem(garden)).join('');
  document.getElementById('listings').innerHTML = listHtml;
});
```

```html
<div id="listings"></div>
```

**But BEWARE**: As it is written, if one of the gardens had a name or address with HTML in it, it would inject that into your HTML. At best, it would mess up your display. At worst, it could allow malicious script to be executed in your users' browsers.

I would *highly recommend* using a framework that's designed to solve this kind of problem: react, vue, or angular. Your code will be simpler and safer.

Comment: thank you so much!! This makes sense to have name and address properties for gardenData. Thank you for the example and for taking the time to break this down the way you did, this is really helpful for understanding. I will note that for IDs and classes. 

Thank you for the beware note - I definitely do not want that. React protects against cross-scripting because of the $$ security feature since its a javaScript primitive, right? 


I'll make this in React and hook it to Wordpress. I love React but haven't easily found a way to use it in Wordpress, so this'll be a good exercise.

Comment: React protects against script injection because its templating language (jsx) doesn't generate HTML directly: it creates an object called a React Element, which keeps track of the template HTML separately from the values that get injected into it. Unless you use the aptly-named `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute, the values that get inserted into the jsx code are HTML-encoded when rendering, without your having to think about it.

Comment: Thank you again - this was really helpful to read, and I appreciate the breakdown of info for how React protects against script injection :) and that is a very appropriate attribute name considering LOL